# Como buscar palabra en un texto

Tags: php

Tengo un string que proviene de una base de datos el cual leo con `fetch_array()`. Ejemplo:

```
$row=$query->fetch_array();
```

Lo que me gustaría es inteceptar palabras. Por ejemplo, si en ese string existe la palabra "CARRO", poner esa palabra en negrita, es decir, encerrar dicha palabra en una etiqueta HTML ya sea `<b>` o `<a>`. ¿Alguien sabe cómo podría hacer lo que necesito?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si entiendo bien quieres al string que te devuelve la base de datos, buscar una palabra y enmarcarla con etiquetas html. Mira si te sirve:

```
str_replace("CARRO","<b>CARRO</b>",string);
```

Comment: bueno se cambian los valores fijos por variables y ya esta, no?

Comment: justo lo que queria gracias pana!